# Como interactuo con jQuery en Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

estoy empezando a probar Electron, y tengo una pequeña gran consulta en lo que se trata de utilizar funciones propias y demás... Estoy traspasando de a poco lo que ya había hecho para lo que sería la versión web, por ende todo siempre estuvo funcionando al probarlos en el localhost...

Actualmente tengo una función de prueba en configs.js, que debe de llamar al js de sweetalert para mostrar un mensaje... pero al ejecutar mi proyecto de Electron, al clickear el botón en la consola me sale esto:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: en_proceso is not defined
```

(cosa que via web sin problema me funciona)

Les dejo aquí como enlace mis códigos, para que no sea tan largo esta pregunta

```
package.json:  https://pastebin.com/8LFN1d1E
main.js:       https://pastebin.com/HDhi2v0s
index.html:    https://pastebin.com/rKQ1gXkp
configs.js:    https://pastebin.com/zW1cHbLR
```

Answer (score -1):

Instalas jquery por medio de `npm install`
Y en tu **main.js** o como lo tengas

```
var $ = require 'jquery';
```

Comment: jQuery ya lo tengo de esta forma:

    `<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./assets/js/jquery.js');</script>`

y el SweetAlert de forma cruda me funciona sin problemas (al meterlo directo en un onclick por cualquier boton/link que tenga)... Pero a la hora de querer utilizar alguna funcion que haya creado (y que lo guardo en configs.js), en consola me dice que la función no ha sido definida

Comment: ya intentaste en tu archivo de funciones hacer `module.exports = nameFunc` y cada función creas un archivo, entonces en tu main sea el html o el js, haces `var funcX = require('./path/to/file')`